# Does this site have an inherent disadvantage due to Shabbat?

Tags: discussion, site-statistics, sabbath-observance

Naturally many of the users of this stackexchange site are going to be observant Jews who keep the laws of Shabbat. This means that many users will not be using the site at all for one day a week. Does this put us at a disadvantage in general and is there any way to make sure that this fact is noted when being evaluated as a beta site? I would be interested in knowing if there was any reflection of this type of drop in traffic during the mi.yodeya days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the other hand, the "professional" Stacks also have substantial dip over the weekends.
"Professional" i.e. not the hobbyist sites such as RPG, Boardgames, etc.   Rather the programming sites, DBA, PM, Security, etc...
I can speak for ITSecurity.SE, weekends (Sat. *and* Sundays) drop down to near ghosttown levels, then bounce back up.

Overall, the SEI folk seem to look more at the trending, and not specifics of a given day(s).
So, I wouldnt worry about it.

Comment: Indeed.  [Substantial](http://www.quantcast.com/profile/trafficGraph?wunit=wd%3Acom.stackoverflow&drg=&dty=ar&gl=3mo&reachType=period&dtr=dd&width=720&country=UK&ggt=large&showDeleteButtons=true&v=-1714374298).

Comment: oo, preeetttyyyy

Answer (score 4):

To your last point, here's a graph from mi.yodeya's hit counter for April 2011.

You can see significant dips on:

- Sabbaths: April 2, 9, 16, 23, and 30
- Passover first days: April 19 and 20 (latter less so because only observed outside of Israel)
- Passover last days: April 25 and 26 (latter less so because only observed outside of Israel)

[image: Graph showing April 2011 data for Page Loads, Unique Visits, and Returning Visits]

Answer (score 1):

It will definitely make it hard (but not impossible) to get the [Enthusiast](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/badges/22/enthusiast) badge

Comment: ... and yet, some people that I have every reason to believe are Shabbat-keeprs have it. I don't know what the trick is. I have trouble conceiving of someone who's more enthusiast-ic about this site than I've been, and yet, I've never achieved that badge.

Comment: It's easy - hop on Friday afternoon, and again right after havdala... and *then* go wash the Shabbat dishes :)

Comment: @AviD According to [this](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/117/the-fanatic-badge/118#118) analysis, it'd have to be quite late Friday afternoon for me (Central Time). I guess the dishes-postponing technique would help me in the Winter.

Comment: @AviD interesting. I was under the impression that it worked by 24 hour periods, and not by calendar days. Guess not.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere (on meta.SO?) about browser plug-ins that continually ping the SE sites for updates. If you put your computer to sleep for shabbes, this might serve the same purpose.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, I've twice made it well into the 20s (consecutive days), only to just miss it on a crucial MoTzaSh"K.

Comment: @SethJ (et al) it's midnight-to-midnight UTC.  I earned Fanatic last winter (in the yomtov-free zone) by doing the "Friday afternoon, then after havdalah and before UTC midnight (local 7PM)" thing.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I think those of us in Central Time have about as hard of a time getting that badge as anybody.