# Is there an easy way to print a question along with all its answers and comments?

Tags: feature-request

A few minutes ago, I posted a question that has an interesting discussion. I'd like to print it to show it to my rav and discuss it further.

I generally use Chrome and occasionally IE. Clicking "print" captures the entire web page. I'd like something that focuses on just the questions. answers and comments w/ something similar to the "printer-friendly format" button that you see on many web sites. That usually displays a separate page or pop-up window, and it is easy to print that. A download and / or convert to PDF would be an even better feature.

Is there a simple work-around to do this, and / or could any of these features be added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://StackPrinter.com is made to do exactly this.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're doing, but i printed out a few questions to use at the Seder, and this is what i got:

[image: printout of a question from the site]

That seems pretty printer-friendly to me!