# Questions not well received when none have negative votes!

Tags: support, asking-questions

Here is the record for my questions on this Mi Yodeya site

[image: screenshot of user's profile]

Yet (on the fast of Av of all times) I get this offensive message warning me that I am near to being banned because of some problems with my questions!

[image: screenshot of warning message user received when trying to ask a question]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26277/discussion-between-barlop-and-double-aa).

Answer (score 6):

Wow. With that record, I would be unpleasantly surprised to get this message, too.

It's important to note that this message was triggered by an automatic process, not by a person. So, it's not that someone's coming after you on the Fast of Av. Also, [apparently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256615/179), there's a significant margin between this message and an actual question ban.

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) is the big, official writeup from Stack Exchange, the company that hosts Mi Yodeya, explaining as much as they can about the function of these bans (which you haven't reached yet). Have you deleted or had deleted a bunch of posts recently?

I'm sorry you're seeing this, and I hope it goes away soon. If you would like advice on improving a specific post, which would certainly help, please ask here or in our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/vdibarta-bam); I'm sure people will be happy to help.

Comment: No I have not deleted any posts. The system has erred and your link doesn't address that. I may be on the verge of an automatic ban for no good reason. Your answer does not address that at all - that link https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th    does not address when the system is in error. And to offer me a post about how to improve my question asking skills, and under these circumstances, is almost like you winding me up.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm offering everything I can that might be helpful. I have no more sight into the system or control over it than you do.

Comment: Is it possible that your computer or IP address is shared by other Mi Yodeya users?

Comment: If that were the case then they should get the message not me

Comment: @barlop The system might intentionally group people asking questions from the same IP address together to prevent people from creating multiple accounts and using them for voting fraud, etc.

Answer (score 2):

That is very odd.  You have one deleted question (score 0, closed and later deleted by the automatic cleanup script), and one other [closed question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47659/472) that you might be able to rework into an on-topic one.  You have no downvoted questions at the time I'm writing this.

I see you've asked two question since taking that screen shot; did you get this warning for both of them?

Comment: You write "I see you've asked two question since taking that screen shot; did you get this warning for both of them?" <--  I got that message for one but not since.

Comment: Thanks.  Please let us know if you get it again.