# Let's fix our now-broken images

Tags: discussion, editing

Stack Exchange is in the process of [switching to HTTPS on all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/162102).  As part of this, they have already fixed links to images hosted on imgur (which is where images go if you upload them in a post).  At the same time, they [stopped showing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291947/162102) images that are to other sites and use HTTP in the URLs.

I wasn't clever enough to notice the implications of that before this week's SEDE update, when it would still have been easy to grab a list of affected posts.  Now the query is more complicated, but fellow moderator [jefromi](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/1672/jefromi) has created a [query](http://data.stackexchange.com/judaism/query/639580/posts-with-more-image-markdown-than-html-images) that we think finds most of them.  This query found 32 images on our main site.

Let's try to fix those posts.  Some image links might have rotted since posting (i.e. those images were missing last week too); others exist just fine but at HTTP URLs.  The task is to:

1. Find the image -- if the original URL works, great; if not, try the Wayback Machine.
2. If the site serving the image works with HTTPS, fix the URL in the post.
3. If not, decide (a) whether the image is valuable and (b) if so, whether it seems kosher to upload a copy to imgur.  (If in doubt about use of other people's intellectual property, don't.)  Make appropriate changes to the post.
4. While you're in there anyway, see if the image needs [better alt text](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3426/472) and fix that.

I'll post the list of affected posts (according to that query) in an answer.  Please move them to the "done" section if you fix them.

Comment: You're expecting a lot of me. I'm 59. You're looking for someone between the ages of 14 and 30.

Comment: @BruceJames ? I'm sorry, I don't follow.  Anyway, it's a collective "let's", not an individual imperative.  Not everybody is going to participate and that's fine.

Answer (score 3):

**Done:**

[Is there an authentic source for such a partial hair covering for women?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/62580)
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/125
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/296
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/300
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/80291
[What's the best rewording of "midas harachamim aleinu hisgalgli" for those uncomfortable with it?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2996)
[Is the cat figurine thing a problem at kosher Chinese restaurants?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/2371)
[Is there a chart available displaying all Hebrew letters and vowels?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8839)
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/117
[Can you recommend an alternative outer talit bag?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/119)
[How do you pick a Hagada to use at the Seder?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/569)
[What is the font with points in the middle of the letters called?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5879)
[What Kashrut Agency Uses this Symbol?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34000)
[What is the reason for V-neck Titzis?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16433)
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/59135
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8584
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50298
[Why do Lubavitch talisos ensure tzitzis hang off the side?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18316)

**Not done:**

[Reliability of the OKS](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12387)
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26167
[Are old-fashioned razors kosher?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/30026)
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/33320
[What halachic issues are involved in the use of a trouser press in the nine days?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43842)
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/46140
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56449
[Reason for Sepharadi Qeri'at Shema' Custom](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/69566)
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/76987
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/78177

**false positive**?

https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/78315
https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/76129
[Tribe Plates on door of Heichal Shlomo](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47818)
[Searching for a halachic diagram of female anatomy](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56586)

Comment: As far as I can tell, the first two links go to posts without any images in them, but with links to Amazon pages in them. Am I missing something, or is the query?

Comment: @IsaacMoses in the first one I see `<img src="https://www.assoc-amazon.com/e/ir?t=miyodeya-20&l=ur2&o=1" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" style="border:none !important; margin:0px !important;" />` -- which looks like a tracker pixel so could probably go away, though I see it's also https already so I don't know why this query picked it up.  I see a similar img tag in the second one.

Comment: It seems that there are some things going on behind the scenes involving 1) replacing markdown image tags with html tags (maybe?) and 2) auto-inserting Amazon tracker images for Amazon links, that confuse matters. I think we can just move posts whose only `img` is one of these Amazon trackers to "Done."

Comment: It's pretty annoying how, within the user-editable markdown, markdown links to Amazon pages have been replaced with these raw-html monstrosities, inline. I thought that this was being done automatically to Amazon links at render time. Did this edit of the markdown input happen recently?

Comment: ... But I don't see this effect on [more recent Amazon links](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3796/dealing-with-anger/73492), so perhaps it was just part of migration of SE 1.0 content to SE 2.0, and therefore only applies to a handful of posts. Perhaps it would be worthwhile, for hygiene purposes, to just fix those posts now to use clean markdown.

Comment: @IsaacMoses it looks like a property of older posts -- whether that means SE 1.0, or some change SE made to handling of Amazon links in the last 6 years, or something else, I don't know.  Later posts have actual missing images -- what used to be images has been replaced by links to images -- and that's something SE did in bulk a few days ago.  I don't know all the ramifications, but I came across a SEDE query that looks like it'll help us deal with the aftermath, hence the post.  I agree it's frustrating, but the goal of full HTTPS seems good.