# Referencer KSA is down

Tags: discussion, user-scripts, referencer

I recently edited a [post](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81065/5323) on the main site, adding links with the [Referencer](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1758/mi-yodeya-referencer-a-syntax-for-linking-to-sources) as necessary. However, when I clicked on the link to test it, I found that http://www.yonanewman.org/kizzur/kizzur1.html is no longer available online. I briefly considered linking to an [archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20160423100439/http://www.yonanewman.org:80/kizzur/kizzur1.html) instead, but ultimately chose [Sefaria](http://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.13.3?lang=bi).

#### The Referencer should be updated, if possible.

If possible, someone (@Hod?) should fix the Referencer so that it can be used effectively in the future. I lack the technical ability to do so. I don't think we should use the Internet Archive; I think Sefaria's Kitzur looks much nicer.

#### Historical posts should be updated.

We should consider making an effort to fix posts that have used the Referencer links to the KSA, so they no longer point to dead pages (à la the ongoing [image project](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4261/lets-fix-our-now-broken-images)). I don't know how to make a query to find all of the yonanewman.org links, but the KSA [is referenced in over 400 posts](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=kitzur%20shulchan%20aruch), so there could be very many posts that need fixing.

Comment: Also, when writing this, I realized that the Referencer no longer works on Meta: [ksa 1]. This could be because of the [https update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/266359); we changed from meta.judaism.SE to judaism.meta.SE ...maybe? I don't know how this works.

Comment: [This query](http://data.stackexchange.com/judaism/query/644024/url-finder) finds only 37, but I took the simple-minded approach of just looking for that domain.  (I also tried to parameterize it instead of baking in the URL, but either I'm doing something wrong or variables don't play well inside patterns.)