# Why are some profile pictures not showing up?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, display

I've noticed that some pictures here on the site have not been showing up (example: my profile picture). What is the reason for this?

Comment: Yours shows for me. Can you [edit] into the question details about what browser you're using, and also perhaps a list of members with indication of whether their pictures show up, so maybe someone can find commonality? Also, do the pictures not show up anywhere or only in specific places (on the profile page itself, attached to posts, on the Mi Yodeya, on Mi Yodeya Meta, on other SE sites, in chat)? Finally, to help SE developers track this down, it may help if you indicate when this started (so they can relate the issue to a specific rollout of the software).

Comment: I can also see your picture.

Comment: I cannot see Ezra's profile picture on Chrome on Windows or Chrome on Android, or on IE 11 on Windows. I also can't see [Al Berko's](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/15579/al-berko?tab=profile).

Comment: @IsaacMoses I also use Chrome, and I cannot see Al Berko's either.

Comment: It's not just user profile pictures. I suspect that I can't see anything on i.stack.imgur.com. I picked [a post](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/711/a-letter-prohibiting-television/16086#16086) with images in it at random from [this list](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3426/lets-make-mi-yodeya-more-friendly-to-people-and-machines-that-cant-see-images) and found that I couldn't see the images, which are i.stack.imgur -hosted.

Comment: I tried editing a post and uploading a picture, and the preview failed to show it to me. When I replaced it with [this](https://i.imgur.com/qaGKN5r.jpg) random picture from regular imgur.com, it showed fine.

Comment: It's not just Mi Yodeya. Check out the front page of [Photos.SE], which conveniently features a i.stack.imgur -hosted photo.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313779/is-stack-imgur-currently-down

Comment: When I shift-F5 (hard refresh) pages with images I couldn't see before (including this one, with ezra's avatar), I can now see them. The problem may be fixed.

Comment: @IsaacMoses It's fixed by me too! :D